# Sonarqube: scan subproject instead of whole project with custom gradle task

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have to run Sonarqube analysis for a Java project which is a subproject among 4 others, something like below:

```
  Parent-project
    -> serviceA
       -> src/main/java/...
    -> serviceB
       -> src/main/java/...
    -> serviceC
       -> src/main/java/...
    -> serviceD
       -> src/main/java/...
  -> gradle.properties
  -> sonar.gradle
```

I know that I can exclude unwanted services as below:

```
project(":serviceB") {
        sonarqube {
            skipProject = true
        }
    }
```

However the problem is that I do not own the parent project and hence cannot make changes in the global sonar.gradle file as this is being shared other services as well.

Is there a way to have a sonar.gradle only for my project (serviceA), and a gradle task that runs analysis only for my service? 
I am completely lost here because the documentation does not seem to tell anything about this.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: looking answer for same..

Comment: Hey @AasthaJain, I just posted a solution that worked for me. Let me know if this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. You can actually exclude the unwanted projects under the parent project using following setting in your sonar.gradle:

```
project(":project-1") {
    sonarqube {
        skipProject = true
    }
}
 
project(":project-2") {
    sonarqube {
        skipProject = true
    }
}
```

If you want even more control to a level that you don't want to exclude a whole sub-project but want to include only a part of the sub-project (for example a common shared library where multiple teams contribute and you want to analyze just your team's code), you can do it something like below:

```
project(":common-project") {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.inclusions", "src/main/java/**/common/**"
        }
    }
}
```